# Cloud build CI/CD & k8s files

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using cloud build and GKE k8s cluster and i have setup CI/CD from github to cloud build.

I want to know is it good to add CI build file and Dockerfile in the repository or manage config file separately in another repository?

Is it good to add Ci & k8s config files with business logic repository?

What is best way to implement CI/CD cloud build to GKE with managing CI/k8 yaml files

Comment: This tutorial on GitOps style CI/CD with Cloud Build could be helpful (the declarative infrastructure files are kept in a separate repo, while dockerfile or cloudbuild.yaml in same repo sas project): https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build

Comment: @chriscross thankyou for sharing a link i was following same but my concern is that can't i add one cloud build file and all k8s deployment yaml file with application code repository instead of making two different repo for CI/CD

Comment: I guess the idea is to separate (k8s yamls in  one repo from dockerfile/cloudbuild together with app code in another) because the app repo is needed for building the image and only after it was successful, yamls should be applied. also you might not want to trigger a new build just from changes made to the yamls.

Comment: also you can have multiple branches in the k8s yaml repo that match your infrastructure environments like dev, qa, stage, production.

Comment: @chriscross Thankyou so much got my answer the reason. thankyou so much for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add deployment directives, typically in a dedicated folder of your project, which can in turn use a cicd repository

See "[`kelseyhightower/pipeline-application`](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/pipeline-application)" as an example, where:

> Changes pushed to any branch except master should trigger the following actions:
>
> - build a container image tagged with the build ID suitable for deploying to a staging cluster
> - clone the [pipeline-infrastructure-staging repo](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/pipeline-infrastructure-staging)
> - patch the pipeline deployment configuration file with the staging container image and commit the changes to the pipeline-infrastructure-staging repo
>
> The pipeline-infrastructure-staging repo will deploy any updates committed to the master branch.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing the answer. got a clear idea about CI/CD probably i have to create two repo only.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that:

The best solution for storing  **Dockerfile or build config file** should be the remote repository. For dockerfiles this is supported as "**Native Docker support**" in gcloud.

You can use different host repositories like:

- **Cloud Source Repository**
- **Bitbucket**
- **GitHub**

As an example structure for **build config yaml file** you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#dockerfile_and_build_config_file), informations about [cloud build  concepts and tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/).